# wrong amount strtotime on 2014-03-31 only

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
$startTimeStamp = strtotime(2014-03-28);

$endTimeStamp = strtotime(2014-03-31);

$datediff = $endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp;

$amount_days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

When date 2014-03-31 is end date the amount is incorrect.

There is exactly 3600 seconds (1 hour) short in the strtotime calculation.

Why is this?

Comment: You might want to put `2014-03-28` and `2014-03-31` in quotes like `"2014-03-28"`.

Comment: Assuming you put in the quotes as GhostGambler suggests, the problem isn't in the code provided. How are you determining that it's off? Please show the rest of the code.